# Cloud Run Uncaught signal: 11 after upgrade Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-run

I upgraded my project to Laravel 9 with PHP8. But since I deployed on Cloud Run I randomly have this errors in the Cloud Run logs :

`Uncaught signal: 11, pid=17, tid=17, fault_addr=4294967296017.`

So the query is aborded with 503 error : `GET 503 898 octets 682 msChrome 109 https://...`

Here is my php-custom.ini :

```
max_execution_time = 500
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
memory_limit = 800M
max_file_uploads = 100
```

And my opcache.ini :

```
[opcache]
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.validate_timestamps=0
opcache.max_accelerated_files=32531
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.max_wasted_percentage=10
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=64
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.jit_buffer_size=100M
opcache.jit=1235
```

And my dockerfile :

```
FROM php:8.2.3-apache as base

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

WORKDIR /app

# Install PHP dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        unzip \
        locales \
        pdftk \
    && sed -i -e 's/# fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath

# Env
ENV LC_ALL fr_FR.UTF-8 
ENV LANG fr_FR.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE fr_FR:en

# Copy project, vhost.conf, config php and install composer
COPY . .
COPY docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY docker/custom.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/custom.ini
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN sed -i 's/80/${PORT}/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf

# Add permissions
RUN mkdir -p /app/vendor \
    mkdir -p /app/storage/logs \
    && useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user \
    && mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer \
    && chown -R $user:$user /home/$user \
    && chown -R $user:$user /app \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && chmod +x docker/startup-dev.sh \
    && chmod +x docker/startup-prod.sh

EXPOSE 8080

FROM base as development
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano
ENTRYPOINT ["docker/startup-dev.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
USER $user

FROM base as production
COPY docker/opcache.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/opcache.ini
RUN composer clearcache && composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
ENTRYPOINT ["docker/startup-prod.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
USER $user
```

I don't know how to reproduce the bug because it's very random, but I noticed the error appears after the Cloud Run cold start. I don't know if the problem is caused by my opcache config. My Cloud run service has 1 CPU and 2 GO memory.

I don't know how to fix that.

**Edit**

I'm adding 2 graphs when I got the error :

[image: 2023-03-14 error]

[image: 2023-03-17 error]

Comment: During the container lifecycle, when the instance is offloaded, the signal 11 (SIGTERM) is sent to the instance and you have 10s to handle it and to perform ultimate action before the instance disappears. It's not new. Maybe your new version of Laravel handles it now. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#instance-shutdown

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks. I checked the graphs during the occurrence of the error, and I believe that we are experiencing the scenario where 'if a container instance that is processing requests needs to be shut down, new incoming requests are routed to other instances and requests currently being processed are given time to complete.' However, in my case, new incoming requests are not being routed to other instances, and I am just getting a 503 error. I have updated my question to show you the graphs. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to resolve this issue. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I agree, it's strange, after 15 minutes, the instance is offloaded, and you can catch a signal 11 . Until there, it's normal. But it's not normal that get or option requests are routed to the instance that is offloaded. I think you can open a support case to Google.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I think I have a idea. I see this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199562/205617 and I didn't set `M` to my `opcache.memory_consumption=256` so it's considered as bytes by default. And when I upgraded to php8 I added jit `opcache.jit_buffer_size=100M` and I specifed `100M` so I think there is a conflict because the `memory_consumption` is < to `jit_buffer_size`

Comment: Ok the problem is about `jit` I tried to add `M` to `memory_consumption` but I have signal 11 again. But when I remove  opcache.jit_buffer_size=100M and opcache.jit=1235 I don't have any problem. So the jit configuration doesn't work actually I do'nt know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. That is not about Cloud Run. The problem is the JIT configuration. I changed this:

```
opcache.jit=1235
```

to

```
opcache.jit=1255
```

According to this : https://php.watch/versions/8.0/JIT#jit-opcache-jit-values I tried both too :

```
tracing: An alias to the granular configuration 1254.
function: An alias to the granular configuration 1205.
```

And it works too if you don't want to use 1255. But I used `1255` because on this [Pull Request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/8535/files) I seen lot of Unit Tests with 1255 configuration.